# piping /dev/tty to ipython without losing formatting or tab completion

Tags: python, tty, ncurses

I want to insert code into the beginning of an ipython session, and then use ipython interactively.

Let's say I run `cat <(echo 'import itertools') /dev/tty | ipython`. I get an interactive iPython console, but without any coloured formatting or tab completion. How do I keep these things?

[edit]

It would be great if someone could explain *why* ipython loses all of these features when I run the above code. And to explain how to restore those features in a way that's not specific to ipython. Using `/dev/tty` seems like the most Unixy solution to the problem. It's a shame it doesn't work.

Comment: You can put import lines in your ipython config file. https://ipython.org/ipython-doc/stable/config/intro.html

Comment: @MarkPlotnick Good suggestion

Comment: @MarkPlotnick Any insight you have to my extended question would be great

Comment: Which version of ipython are you using? It looks like older versions use readline for reading input and newer versions use prompt_toolkit . Either of those might not have full interactive functionality when the input is a pipe rather than a terminal.

Comment: @MarkPlotnick 7.9.0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is an ad-hoc solution specific to ipython. Run `ipython -ic 'import itertools'` instead of `cat <(echo 'import itertools') /dev/tty | ipython`.

### More flexibility

It's possible to pipe arbitrary output from other programs into ipython using the backticks ``` `` ```. Specifically, substitute any CLI code whatsoever in place of WHATEVER in

```
ipython -ic "`WHATEVER`"
```

The extra double-quotes "" are needed to stop the terminal from splitting on spaces